# case when statement in oracle across tables

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi apologies for formatting but im stumped and frustrated and i just need some help.

I've got two tables.  I have made a good faith attempt to follow community standards but just in case it doesnt work, Table A has 3 columns 'ID', to identify a sales rep, 'Start' to indicate what company term they started, and 'Sales' to indicate their sales in that first term.  Table B is just an expansion of Table A where it lists all terms (i marked it as quarters) a sales person was there and their sales.

### Table A

```
+----+---------+-------+
| ID | Quarter | Sales |
+----+---------+-------+
|  1 |     141 |    30 |
|  2 |     151 |    50 |
|  3 |     151 |    80 |
+----+---------+-------+
```

### Table B

```
+----+---------+-------+
| ID | Quarter | Sales |
+----+---------+-------+
|  1 |     141 |    30 |
|  1 |     142 |    25 |
|  1 |     143 |    45 |
|  2 |     151 |    50 |
|  2 |     152 |    60 |
|  2 |     153 |    75 |
|  3 |     151 |    80 |
|  3 |     152 |    50 |
|  3 |     153 |    70 |
+----+---------+-------+
```

My desired output is a table with ID, start term, sales from that term, second term, sales from that term, etc. for the first 6 terms an employee is there

my code is this

```
select a.id, start, a.sales,
case when a.start+1 = b.quarter then sales end as secondquartersales,
case when a.start+2 = b.quarter then sales end as thridquartersales,.....
from tablea a
left join tableb b
on a.id = b.id;
```

it gives nulls for all case when statements.  please help

Comment: Your query as written should generate an error because `sales` is ambiguous and `q` is not defined.

Comment: meant b instead of q.  long day.

Comment: Could you add expected result in tabular format as well ? My second question would be what is the relation between `start `and `quarter` ? Why do you add `start+1` ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 because of uneven starting times.  I want to see what an employees sales are on their second quarter, third quarter etc. start+1, start+2 etc should give that, at least I hope.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code **or data** - use formatted text. Thanks.

Comment: On a side note: Table A is superfluous in this data model, as the data can easily be got from table B. Better don't store data redundantly in order to avoid potential inconsistencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe try GROUP BY

```
create table a ( id number, strt number, sales number);
create table b (id number, quarter number , sales number);

insert into a values (1,141,30);
insert into a values (2,151,50);
insert into a values (3,151,80);

insert into b values ( 1,141,30);
insert into b values ( 1,142,25);
insert into b values ( 1,143,45);
insert into b values ( 2,151,50);
insert into b values ( 2,152,60);
insert into b values ( 2,153,75);
insert into b values ( 3,151,80);
insert into b values ( 3,152,50);
insert into b values ( 3,153,70);

 select a.id, a.strt, a.sales, 
    max(case when a.strt+1 = b.quarter then b.sales end ) as secondquartersales,
    max(case when a.strt+2 = b.quarter then b.sales end ) as thridquartersales
from  a, b
where  a.id = b.id
group by  a.id, a.strt, a.sales;
```

OR PIVOT

```
select * from (
select a.id, 
    case when a.strt+1 = b.quarter then 'Q2'  
        when a.strt+2 =  b.quarter then  'Q3'  
        when a.strt+3 =  b.quarter then  'Q4' 
        when a.strt = b.quarter then 'Q1'end  q,
        b.sales sales
    
from  a, b
where  a.id = b.id) 
pivot ( max(nvl(sales,0)) for Q in ('Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'));
```

Comment: This is a very good solution. (Or rather two at that.) But this join syntax was replaced with explicit joins in Standard SQL 1992, which was even years before MySQL came into existence. Don't use comma-separated joins. We are not in the 1980s anymore. Use `FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id` instead.

Comment: If it is not helpful I can delete.

Comment: Thanks for your help @MonikaLewandowska This helped me a lot.

Comment: There is any regulations with the rule that only ANSI SQL is allowed here? I can't find.... Can you share a link or sth?  I don't feel good about sb changing my answer. I put much effort to do that but I have no longer certaity that my answer is still correct and accurate.

Comment: There is no such rule! The question is tagged for Oracle, so an answer using Oracle syntax is appropriate.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith thank you, good to know. I have started to be affraid of adding any new answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This is valid ANSI 92 SQL, as it is an inner join. The whole ANSI style version is just syntax candy.